# kotlin - javascript function is not being called

Tags: javascript, android, kotlin

I'm building an android app in kotlin with the purpose of sendind user-defined parameters to a robot via JSON. In the side of the robot (which uses ROS) everything is set for receiving JSON objects. However, I'm still having a problem with the app: my app has an activity tasked with receiving the parameters, transform them to an appropiate data type (int or float) and send them to a javascript function which makes the connection with the robot's websocket server and publishes the parameters as a message to a ROS topic.the activity has other functions like resetting the parameters to their default values and going to other activities, but those functions work perfectly.

Here's the code of the activity:

```
package com.example.jorge.autonavi3at

import android.content.Intent
import android.os.Build
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.support.annotation.RequiresApi
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog
import android.view.View
import android.webkit.WebResourceRequest
import android.webkit.WebView
import android.webkit.WebViewClient
import android.widget.SeekBar
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_triprobot.*

const val maxdef = 20
const val mindef = 4

class triprobot : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_triprobot)
        supportActionBar!!.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false)
        supportActionBar!!.setHomeButtonEnabled(false)
        robosender.webViewClient = roboBridge()
        robosender.settings.javaScriptEnabled = true
        robosender.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/rostalkerrobo.html")

        speedslider.progress = 20
        robospeed.text = speedslider.progress.toString()
        speedslider.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(object : SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener{
            override fun onProgressChanged(seekbar: SeekBar?, progress: Int, fromUser: Boolean) {
                robospeed.setText(progress.toString())
            }

            override fun onStartTrackingTouch(seekbar: SeekBar?) {

            }

            override fun onStopTrackingTouch(seekbar: SeekBar?) {

            }
        })
        maxdist.setText(maxdef.toString())
        mindist.setText(mindef.toString())
        maxdist.setSelectAllOnFocus(true)
        mindist.setSelectAllOnFocus(true)

    }

    fun getRobParam(view: View){


        var paramerror = java.lang.Boolean.FALSE
        val speed = robospeed.text.toString()
        val tspeed = intconvert(speed)
        if (tspeed < 20 || tspeed > 100) {
            paramerror = java.lang.Boolean.TRUE
        }

        val dmax = maxdist.text.toString()
        val tdmax = intconvert(dmax)
        val dmin = mindist.text.toString()
        val tdmin = intconvert(dmin)
        if (tdmax < tdmin || tdmax > 20 || tdmin < 4 || tdmin > 10) {
            paramerror = java.lang.Boolean.TRUE
        }

        val imageh = imheight.text.toString()
        val timageh = intconvert(imageh)
        val imagew = imwidth.text.toString()
        val timagew = intconvert(imagew)
        val xc = centerx.text.toString()
        val txc = intconvert(xc)
        val yc = centery.text.toString()
        val tyc = intconvert(yc)
        val interior = intrad.text.toString()
        val tinterior = intconvert(interior)
        val exterior = extrad.text.toString()
        val texterior = intconvert(exterior)
        val mirror = ksi.text.toString()
        val tmirror = floatconvert(mirror)

        if (paramerror) {
            confirmError()
        } else {
            confirmParam(tspeed,tdmax,tdmin,timageh,timagew,txc,tyc,tinterior,texterior,tmirror) //This goes to JS call
        }
    }

    fun retmainfromrob(view: View) {
        // Do something in response to button
        val intent = Intent(this,tripconfig::class.java)
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP)
        startActivity(intent)

    }

    fun resetRobParam(view: View){
        speedslider.progress = 20
        maxdist.setText(maxdef.toString())
        mindist.setText(mindef.toString())
    }

    fun gotoApp(view: View){
        val intent = Intent(this,tripappli::class.java)
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP)
        startActivity(intent)
    }

    fun intconvert(convcase: String): Int {
        return if (convcase != "") {
            Integer.parseInt(convcase)
        } else {
            0
        }
    }

    fun floatconvert(convcase: String): Float {
        return if (convcase != "") {
            java.lang.Float.parseFloat(convcase)
        } else {
            0f
        }
    }

    fun confirmError() {
        val errorparam = ErrorDialogFragment()
        errorparam.show(supportFragmentManager, "bad_parameter")
    }

//Here is the JS call
    fun confirmParam(rspeed : Int,maxl : Int,minl : Int,iheight : Int,iwidth : Int,ppointx : Int, ppointy : Int, irad : Int, erad : Int, kagami : Float)  {
        goodparam.show(supportFragmentManager, "neat_parameter")*/
        val builder = AlertDialog.Builder(this)
        builder.setMessage(R.string.confirm_msg)
                .setTitle(R.string.confirm_param)
                .setPositiveButton(R.string.confirm_positive) { dialog, id ->
                    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
                        robosender.evaluateJavascript("robosend($rspeed, $minl, $maxl, $iheight, $iwidth, $ppointx, $ppointy, $irad, $erad, $kagami);", null)
                    } else {
                        robosender.loadUrl("javascript:robosend($rspeed, $minl, $maxl, $iheight, $iwidth, $ppointx, $ppointy, $irad, $erad, $kagami);")
                    }
                    val intent = Intent(this,tripconfig::class.java)
                    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP)
                    startActivity(intent)
                }.setNegativeButton(R.string.confirm_negative) {dialog, id ->

                }
        builder.show()
    }

    class roboBridge : WebViewClient(){
        @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
        override fun shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view: WebView?, request: WebResourceRequest?): Boolean {
            view?.loadUrl(request?.url.toString())
            return true
        }
    }
}
```

The problem here lies in the javascript function calling. It's simply not occurring.

Here is the HTML code with the javascript function:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="eventemitter2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="roslib.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

    var ros = new ROSLIB.Ros({
      url : 'ws://192.168.3.102:9090'
    });

    var harparam = new ROSLIB.topic({
      ros : ros,
      name : '/p3at_parameters',
      messageType : 'autonavi3at/roboParam',
      latch : true
    });

    function robosend(robovel, mindist, maxdist, imheight, imwidth, ppointx, ppointy, inrad, exrad, ksi){

      var rparam = new ROSLIB.message({
        speed : robovel,
        minrange : mindist,
        maxrange : maxdist,
        height: imheight,
        width : imwidth,
        inradius : inrad,
        exradius : exrad,
        cx : ppointx,
        cy : ppointy,
        mtype : ksi
      });

      harparam.publish(rparam);
    }
</script>
</html>
```

The conection to the websocket server occurs as the ROS console in the robot recognizes my mobile device as a client upon entering to this activity, but when I tap the button that would call the function, it just returns to the main activity without doing anything (using rostopic echo on the robot shows that no message was published).

I tried to test the function by adding a return clause that would return a short message with one of the parameters sent, which would then be shown in the app as a toast, but the toast shows "null".

Then, when I decided to make the message sending directly (no JS function, with some test values that matched the types defined for the message), the message was published.

Is there a Way to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Solved...it was a dumb mistake on my part. Wrote topic and message without initial capital letters (Topic, Message)...